# So many errors occurred when I using the ARC convertion tool

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a project previously built in iOS 4.3. When I tried to invoke the “ARC” conversion tool with

> Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC

from XCode 4.5.2, the tool reports many errors. Some are supposed to be modified automatically by itself, for example the keywords `autorelease/release/retain` should not be used.

The errors seem too many (1,987 occurrences) to resolve by hand. Are there any configuration options that i am missing or should something else be done?

Comment: You should expect anywhere in the range of 250+ for a mid sized project.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have used any third party libraries, if you have used any third party libraries then it won't helps you.that means in this situation it wont automatically converts it to ARC.

Unfortunately ARC manages memory only for objective-c objects, if you have used any C or C++ files then in this case you have to handle memory management yourself

Comment: I tried to exclude the 3rd party source files from the file list of the convertion tool, but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using existing libraries you can simply not use ARC for those libraries and begin using it throughout your app by using a flag.

Add this to your library or files in question to ignore ARC

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

Comment: Yes I tried this too, even I only choose one source file which is definitly written by myself, the tool also reports more than 300 errors.